# Pause the user exiting a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using JavaScript (and/or jQuery), Is it possible to pause the user from exiting a page for a set amount of time *without* showing an alert/confirmation?

(Say the user clicks on a different page or closes the window, a timer should start for three seconds [during which time something happens] and then the next page is loaded or the window closes.)

Answer (score 2):

**No**, it is impossible in modern browsers.

(Moreover, think of how annoying that would be if every popup did that)

The closest you can do is show the dialog using [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onbeforeunload) but you have asked to avoid this.

#### But why would you want to do that?

Worth mentioning, that this is a magical time. You might want to report something to the server but you suddenly can't because the user is leaving. This is one of those times things that are usually considered bad practice like synchronous ajax might make sense.

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not possible. At best you can implement an `onbeforeunload` handler but your options at this point are very limited (you can certainly not 'wait 3 seconds').

Browsers will try to protect the user so this is behavior that browsers enforce and they have incentive to enforce it.

Answer (score 0):

This works in chrome and firefox:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    var now = new Date();
    while( new Date() - now < 3000 );
};
```

It will also drain battery, so you are killing 2 birds with one stone.

Comment: @Bergi I added a sarcastic twist

Comment: Not planning on using this, but could you explain why it will drain battery?

Comment: Because it uses CPU instead of waiting properly